# How to add items to Reminders App in iOS 17.0?

Tags: ios, swift, events, eventkit

I'm building an app that allows the user to add and create events in the Calendar native app for iPhone.
One of the features I'm working on is also to allow the user to add and create items in the Reminder's native app of the iPhone.

From what I've read, the Calendar and Reminders app work with EventKit, and from the documentation, the process of each don't differ too much.

I'm using this code to request permission to access Reminders and the code I use to add the items to the app.

Any thoughts on why is it not working?
Thanks in advance.

```
import Foundation
import EventKit

class EventModel {
    
    let eventStore  = EKEventStore()
    
    func requestAccessForReminders() {
        let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .reminder)
        if status == .authorized {
            print("EKEventStore access for Reminders already granted.")
        } else {
            eventStore.requestFullAccessToEvents { success, error in
                if success && error == nil {
                    print("EKEventStore access for Reminders has been granted.")
                } else {
                    print("EKEventStore access for Reminders request failed with error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addEventToReminders(title: String, startHour: Int, startMinute: Int, duration: Int) -> Void {
        
        let newEvent = EKReminder(eventStore: self.eventStore)
        
        newEvent.title = title
        newEvent.calendar = self.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()
        
        do {
            try eventStore.save(newEvent,
                                commit: true)
        } catch let error {
            print("Reminder failed with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

This is the information I have in the info.plist. (I know is the same message, but that shouldn't be the main cause am I right?)

Comment: Please update your question and clarify how exactly your code is "not working".

Comment: Also, when printing errors, just print `error`, not `error.localizedDescription`.

Comment: @HangarRash the issue is that when I use the methods, nothing happens. I want to add items to the Reminders App, which I expect to happen with the code I provided. 
Authorization process works great but then "eventStore.save" does not.

Comment: @Paulw11 The error I get is 29. From the output I'm seeing, the line         newEvent.calendar = self.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()

doesn't seems to retract anything (although there is a default calendar set up in the Reminders App)

Comment: @Paulw11 that was my question. I wanted to add items to the Reminders App, my initial guess after this issue was that in the end it is not possible (Apple Doc doesn't really help, I might have misunderstood). Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary issue is that you are requesting access to the calendar, not to reminders. Use `requestFullAccessToReminders` for iOS 17+ or `requestAccess(to: .reminder)` for iOS 16- instead of `requestFullAccessToEvents`.

Here's an updated version of your code that correctly requests access to reminders. This code handles iOS 17 as well as older versions of iOS. Obviously you need to call your `requestAccessForReminders()` function before trying to add any reminders. It might be better to provide a completion handler for `requestAccessForReminders` so you know when the request has completed.

```swift
class EventModel {
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    func requestAccessForReminders() {
        let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .reminder)
        switch status {
            case .notDetermined:
                func handleRequestCompletion(success: Bool, error: Error?) {
                    if let error {
                        print("Error trying to request access: \(error)")
                    } else if success {
                        print("User granted access")
                    } else {
                        print("User denied access")
                    }
                }

                if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
                    eventStore.requestFullAccessToReminders { success, error in
                        handleRequestCompletion(success: success, error: error)
                    }
                } else {
                    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .reminder) { success, error in
                        handleRequestCompletion(success: success, error: error)
                    }
                }
            case .restricted:
                print("Restricted")
            case .denied:
                print("Denied") // Offer option to go to the app settings screen
            case .fullAccess, .authorized: // fullAccess is for iOS 17+. authorized is for iOS 16-
                print("Full access")
            case .writeOnly:
                print("Write-only access")
            @unknown default:
                print("Uh-oh, code is out-of-date")
        }
    }

    func addEventToReminders(title: String, startHour: Int, startMinute: Int, duration: Int) -> Void {
        let newEvent = EKReminder(eventStore: self.eventStore)

        newEvent.title = title
        newEvent.calendar = self.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()

        do {
            try eventStore.save(newEvent, commit: true)
        } catch let error {
            print("Reminder failed with error \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG, I don't know how I missed that. It's so obvious. Tested and it's working now. Thanks a lot @HangarRash.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `print` to look at the behavior before save, you will probably find that:

```
print ("defaultCalendarForNewReminders",eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders() as Any)
```

displays:
`defaultCalendarForNewReminders nil`

You should be checking `defaultCalendarForNewReminders`, because it can be empty, but .calendar cannot be.

`func defaultCalendarForNewReminders() -> EKCalendar?`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507543-defaultcalendarfornewreminders

`var calendar: EKCalendar! { get set }`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekcalendaritem/1507169-calendar

If you are working a clean simulator, the `nil` comes from checking from before the app was granted permissions. After permissions, you would see something like this:

`defaultCalendarForNewReminders Optional(EKCalendar <0x60000212af80> {title = Reminders; type = Local; allowsModify = YES; color = #007AFFFF;})`

Even if the Reminders.app was never run.

Comment: My goal here is to add items to the Reminders App. Do you know if this is possible? 
This is what I get after granting permissions: Optional(EKCalendar <0x28325e670> {title = Eventos; type = CalDAV; allowsModify = YES; color = #FF2968;})

With this, does adding items to the Reminders App would be possible?